# Everything is OK but the toast is not showing, "Getting Your Driver" comes again after clicking the "CALL DRIVER"

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation

As I wrote in findDriver(). block Driver key showing with debug but not toasting and the **Call Driver** Button is showing once but after clicking it is moving back to the previous state which is **Getting your Driver**, I have tried my best from my short experience, if anyone can help I am grateful.

```
private void requestPickupHere(String uid) {
        DatabaseReference dbRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.pickup_request_tbl);
        GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
        mGeoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLongitude(), mLastLocation.getLatitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        if (mUserMarker.isVisible())
            mUserMarker.remove();
        //add new marker
        mUserMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Pickup Here").snippet("")
                .position(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        mUserMarker.showInfoWindow();

        btnRequestPick.setText("Getting your DRIVER..");
        findDriver();
    }


    private void findDriver() {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.driver_tbl);
        GeoFire gfDrivers = new GeoFire(databaseReference);
        GeoQuery geoQuery = gfDrivers.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), radius);
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                //if found driver
                if (!isDriverFound) {
                    isDriverFound = true;
                    driverId = key;
                    btnRequestPick.setText("CALL DRIVER");
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Found: " + key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                //if still not found driver
                if (!isDriverFound) {
                    radius++;
                    findDriver();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

> **Debuger view**

with thread set

```
driverId = key;   
btnRequestPick.setText("CALL DRIVER");                        
Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Found: " + key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

> Debuger value

```
this = {Home$6@8357} 
key = "JXJyvoVE4Td5RLlCiEDTcAUMslE2"
location = {GeoLocation@8360} "GeoLocation(25.6269317, 88.1373717)"
driverId = ""
isDriverFound = true
btnRequestPick = {AppCompatButton@8368} "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton{4470e09 VFED..C.. ........ 20,48-700,144 #7f08004c app:id/btnPickupRequest}"
```

**Debug console output:**

```
I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-12694-0](this:0x7765692000,id:0,api:1,p:12694,c:12694) queueBuffer: slot 0 is dropped, handle=0x777427abc0
D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/System.out: port:443
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzjf@3780888
W/System.err:     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1494)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1639)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:705)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzin.zzah(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.4.1:246)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzin.zzam(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.4.1:263)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzin.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.4.1:330)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zziq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.4.1:2)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzah.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.4.1:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.4.1:21)
D/HWUIExtension: MTKProgramCache.generateProgram: 571849130901572
I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-12694-0](this:0x7765692000,id:0,api:1,p:12694,c:12694) queueBuffer: fps=8.83 dur=2265.23 max=1539.49 min=14.80
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-12694-0](this:0x7765692000,id:0,api:1,p:12694,c:12694) queueBuffer: fps=1.18 dur=11019.12 max=10198.47 min=40.01
```

Answer (score 1):

**I do a very silly mistake in see difference**

```
private void requestPickupHere(String uid) {
        DatabaseReference dbRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.pickup_request_tbl);
        GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
        mGeoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLongitude(), // its a latitude place mLastLocation.getLatitude() // its a longitude place), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

> corrected code

```
private void requestPickupHere(String uid) {
        DatabaseReference dbRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.pickup_request_tbl);
        GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(dbRequest);
        mGeoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

> also be sure about proper geoFire version <3.0.0> will not work, use
>   following version

```
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-java:2.3.1'
```